# How to cache images from listview from firebase swift 3

Tags: swift, listview, firebase, caching

I am struggling to comprehend how to cache images in my listview that I have fetched from Firebase. I have checked online and most of the solutions are somewhat different from the style of code I am writing so find it difficult to transfer over. Any solutions would be grateful for the class I have provided below.

```
class StaffListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var staffFirstAndLastName: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var JobTitle: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var staffImageView: UIImageView!

    var databaseRef: DatabaseReference {
        return Database.database().reference()
    }

    var storageRef: Storage {
        return Storage.storage()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    func configureCell(teacher: StaffListsSTRUCT) {


        //this line of code helps sets the imageviews in the list view to nil before loading. 
        self.staffImageView.image = nil

        self.staffFirstAndLastName.text = teacher.staffName
        self.JobTitle.text = teacher.staffJobTitle

        let imageURL = teacher.staffImageViewString!

        self.storageRef.reference(forURL: imageURL).getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (imgData,
            error) in

            if error == nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let data = imgData {
                        self.staffImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)

                    }

                }
            } else {

                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }

        })

    }


}
```

Comment: Use [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) for this.

Comment: what do i do if i need to pass multiple URL's tho? how would that look like?

Comment: You might want to check their docs first. E.g: https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Cheat-Sheet

Comment: When you say 'cache images' what do you mean? If you want to display images in a tableView, you would retrieve data from Firebase (images etc) and store them in an array that's used as a tableView DataSource. That same array is used for the tableView delegate methods to return the number of items in the array as well as populating the cellView's that are created to show the data in the UI. Oh - as a side note you are NOT going to want to download data as those cells are being created. That will be super slow and a terrible experience for the user. Populate the cell from the dataSource.